# Invalid use of non-static member function - Arduino - Automaton

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino, automaton

First project in C++/Arduino coming from a JavaScript background. I'm having some issues with this code! I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Pad\Pad.cpp:48:55: error: invalid use of non-static member function

sensor.begin( 15, 5 ).onChange( change_callback, 3 );
```

Here's the cpp:

```
#include "Pad.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "FastLED.h"
#include "Automaton.h"

extern CRGB leds[64];

Pad::Pad(int val) {
   _val = val;
   _default = CHSV(random(255), 255, 255);
   _cnt = 0;
   fade = false;
  fade_val = 0;
}

void Pad::change_callback( int idx, int v, int up ) {
    Serial.println(v);
    fade_val = v;
}

void Pad::color() {
  my_leds[0] = CHSV(random(255),255,255);
  fade = true;
}

void Pad::init() {
    for(int a = 0 ; a < 8 ; a++) {
      my_leds[a] = _default;
    }
  sensor.begin( 15, 5 ).onChange( change_callback, 3 );
}

void Pad::render() {
    if(fade) {
        int v = map(fade_val, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
        my_leds[0] = CHSV(127,255, v);
        _cnt++;
    }
}
```

I have tried making `change_callback` a static function but then that causes errors with `fade_val`, which is a public class member. I have a feeling this has to do with pointers, which I'm still wrapping my head around.  It's important that each instance of Pad has it's own sensor and own fade_val - they can't be shared (static) across each Pad.

Comment: you need a reference to your Pad object. You should probably use a static function and use the Pad* as your user parameter.

Comment: Hey Garr, can you elaborate on the Pad* as the user parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is convert your Pad::change_callback in a static one. But if you do it, you must to change the scope of fade_val as well to static and somehow it is problematic for you. Another solution is enclose Pad::change_callback in a [std::mem_fun object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun), but again you need to define the scope of this object as static.

My feelings are that you have static single-one resources, like a sensor attached to the board, and need to share it among different instance objects generating this kind of conflict static/instance. If yes, the solution is statically track which is the current instance assigned to the sensor in that time. The easiest way to do it is put the assigned instance in a static variable in order to be found inside a static function call.

And, of course, if you have just a single one instance of Pad in the whole program, make Pad a [singleton](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/cpp/1) or code an one-size poll to make easy to handle that single instance.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions are the way to go here. Unfortunately, the automaton API does not allow to use lambdas with captured [this] yet.

There was a feature request for this, https://github.com/tinkerspy/Automaton/issues/17, maybe I find some time to implement this.